# Python in SPSS - KEEP variables

Tags: python, spss

I have selected the variables I need based on a string within the variable name. I'm not sure how to keep only these variables from my SPSS file.

```
begin program.
import spss,spssaux
spssaux.OpenDataFile(r'XXXX.sav')
target_string = 'qb2'
variables = [var for var in spssaux.GetVariableNamesList() if target_string in var]
vars = spssaux.VariableDict().expand(variables)
nvars=len(vars)
for i in range(nvars):
    print vars[i]
spss.Submit(r"""
SAVE OUTFILE='XXXX_reduced.sav'.
ADD FILES FILE=* /KEEP \n %s.
""" %(vars))
end program.
```

The list of variables that it prints out is correct, but it's falling over trying to KEEP them. I'm guessing it's something to do with not activating a dataset or bringing in the file again as to why there's errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll want to use the `ADD FILES FILE` command before the `SAVE` for your saved file to be the "reduced" file
2. I think your very last line in the python program should be trying to join the elements in the list `vars`. For example: `%( " ".join(vars) )`

Comment: The main problem was the second point. This has fixed it. Could you explain why this was needed? How does this differ to what I originally had?

Comment: The variable vars is compiled as a list so it's elements need to be joined/concatenated and so to form a string as you desire. Please a Print statement with vars before hand and you'll see it's form.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reversing the order of the SAVE OUTFILE and ADD FILES commands? I haven't run this in SPSS via Python, but in standard SPSS, your syntax will write the file to disk, and then select the variables for the active version in memory--so if you later access the saved file, it will be the version before you selected variables.
If that doesn't work, can you explain what you mean by falling over trying to KEEP them?

Comment: I've swapped the order of the SAVE OUTFILE and the ADD FILES, this makes sense, but the errors seem to be something different. Sorry for my slang, by falling over, I meant that the script was erroring at that point, i.e. where it tries to KEEP the variables.

Comment: >Error # 5241 in column 25.  Text: u
>Undefined variable name.  Check spelling, verify the existence of this
>variable.  Has it been dropped or renamed in this command?

>Error # 5242 in column 26.  Text: qb2a_1
>Unexpected or invalid symbol in a variable list.

Comment: When the variables are printed they are correct, but they are not being recognised in the later command. I don't know where it finds the "u" from as this isn't in the list of variables that it prints

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the problem has been solved, but I would like to point out another solution that can be done without writing any Python code.  The extension command SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES defines a macro based on properties of the variables.  This can be used in the ADD FILES command.

SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!selected" 
/PROPERTIES  PATTERN = ".*qb2".
ADD FILES /FILE=* /KEEP !selected.

The SELECT VARIABLES command is actually implemented in Python.  Its selection criteria can also include other metadata such as type and measurement level.